# [React Native]How to open native 'More Options' on Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to open the native popover for Android, which can share a URL to other apps - tried to search for any example but didn't help a lot.

just like the IOS version of it:
https://ivomynttinen.com/content/3-blog/20150928-ios-design-guidelines/ios-activity-sheet.jpg

Anyone has worked on this feature before, any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module [react-native-send-intent](https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-send-intent) has an API that invokes the Android chooser:

```
  SendIntentAndroid.openChooserWithOptions({
    subject: 'Story Title',
    text: 'Message Body'
  }, 'Share Story');
```

The module is pretty small, but if you only want that particular functionality and absolutely nothing else, you can look at how the intent is sent in [the Java code](https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-send-intent/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/burnweb/rnsendintent/RNSendIntentModule.java#L322).

Comment: Just posted to fb RN team, hopefully we can have that soon :)